# undefined when getting value from mongoose database

Tags: angular, express, mongoose, mean-stack

For school I have to make a website with angular using MEAN stack.
My GET method is returning my spells and comments in json object according to Insomnia.

```
router.get('/API/posts/', function(req, res, next) {
  let query = Post.find().populate("comments").populate("spell");
  query.exec(function(err, posts){
  if(err) { return next(err); }
    res.json(posts);
  });
});
```

Whenever I try to use my spell I get an `undefined`. This method gets my items from the `get` method (I get every value except my spell)

```
get posts() : Observable<Post[]> {
return this.http.get(`${this._appUrl}/posts/`)
  .pipe(
    map((list: any[]): Post[] =>
      list.map(Post.fromJSON)
  ));
}
```

My fromJSON method:

```
static fromJSON(json: any): Post {
  const post = new Post(
    json.title,
    json.description,
    json.originalPoster,
    json.category,
    json.spell.map(Spell.fromJSON)
  );
  post._id = json._id;
  post._comments = json.comments;
  return post;
}
```

Everything worked untill I added the spell to my Post module. I've been searching for a very long time so it would be great if you guys could help me

My Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  spell: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Spell'
  },
  originalPoster: String,
  category: String,
  dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  votes: { type: Number, default: 0 }
}); 
mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comment: Share you schema models as well. Thanks

Comment: I've added my PostSchema

Comment: That specific post may not have any spell in it. 

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009808/mongoose-populate-returning-undefined-when-requiring-schema-from-another-file

Comment: I've fixed it. I threw the map out and instead did it like this: 
    `new Spell(json.spell.name, json.spell.level,     json.spell.castingTime, ect)`

This seemed to work strange enough

Answer (score 0):

Try `populate("comments spell");`

Comment: you really need to expand this answer.